# Gnome Terminal hotkey change globally via cli

Tags: command-line, configuration, gnome-terminal

Gnome Terminal has an option to turn off F10 and menu access hotkeys. I've also found out that this option can also be adjusted at 
`/apps/gnome-terminal/global/use_menu_accelerators` and `/apps/gnome-terminal/global/use_mnemonics` in `gconf-editor`.

My question is that how can I make this change

- from the command line
- globally for each user

I'm interested in an Ubuntu 13.04 solution but I the answer seems to be the same for 12.04 at first sight.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: @EricCarvalho: updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gconftool-2` to set those options from command line.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal.

To disable run:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-terminal/global/use_menu_accelerators -t bool false
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-terminal/global/use_mnemonics -t bool false
```

To enable run:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-terminal/global/use_menu_accelerators -t bool true
gconftool-2 -s /apps/gnome-terminal/global/use_mnemonics -t bool true
```